# Create a table presenting celsius, fahrenheit, kelvin and réaumur

Tags: java

Okay. So. Task: create a table like this:

[A table of celsius, fahrenheit, kelvin and réaumur, where celsius goes from 0-20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rExwj.png)

The table is to be based on celsius, which should be presented from 0-20 and then converted accordingly to the other three systems. The convertion is to be done in separate methods.

And I just have no idea what to do. My head is blank. Except for the methods, which I have already done. This is my program so far, but, hey, its not much:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] celsius = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20); 

System.out.println("Celsius" + "\t" + "Kelvin" + "\t" + "Fahrenheit" + "\t" +          
                   "Réaumur");
System.out.println("------------------------------------------");     

}


public static double getKelvin(double cel) {
    double kelvin;
    kelvin = cel + 273.15;
    return (kelvin); 
 }

public static double getFahr(double cel) {
    double fahr1;
    fahr1 = (grader * 9) / 5 + 32;
    return (fahr1); 
}

public static double rea(double cel) {
    double rea1;
    rea1 = (grader * 0.8);
    return (rea1); 
}
}
```

What should I do!? I feel so stupid, but my head is completly blank...
A million thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to loop from 0 to 20. No need for an array to do that. Open your text book to see how for loop work. At each iteration, print the 4 values.

Comment: In your `getFahr` and `rea` methods you do not use the passed `cel` value. Instead you do calculations with some variable called `grader` which is never defined before that.

Comment: generally questions should specific on how to solve a technical problem.  Or fixing a bug.
You are just asking people here to do the assignment for you.

Answer (score -1):

What about something like

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
for(int c : celsius) {
    System.out.print(c);
    System.out.print("\t" + df.format(getKelvin(c)));
    System.out.print("\t" + df.format(getFahr(c)));
    System.out.print("\t" + df.format(rea(c)));
    System.out.println("");
}
```

The decimal separator depends on your system localization settings.

Regards